# Route with generic parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

doubt came here with ASP.NET MVC.

Has as make a system with "areas" that generic?

Example: meusite.com / nome_area {} / {parameter}

where the parameter would say that would appear on the page.

In a news site for example, if the parameter in the URL would: meusite.com / {area} / city_name, content that would appear in the area would be linked that city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you recall when it comes to `Routing`, you know that ordering of route registration is very important. So, generic routes may be difficult to order and hence **not possible**.

You can find more information on [this blog.](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/12/30/asp-net-mvc-2-and-why-dynamic-area-is-not-supported.aspx)